# Determinant of order 2 and 3

Tags: determinant

Can anyone tell me where i can learn how to solve determinants of BCA level ? Actually i wanted to understand everything about determinant and it's all properties . Examples given in my book are in short manner which is unable to understand. So i required an easy way to understand. It would be helpful if anyone can provide a link for easy learning.

Comment: What's BCA? ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: BCA means bachelor of computer applications. It is a three year degree in computer application.